# rxjs: get last value from set of Observables

Tags: rxjs

I have 2 observable and I would like to have the value of the last one which emitted.

Example:

```
private obs1: Observable<number> = interval(1000);
private obs2: Observable<number> = interval(700);

public lastValue; // should take the value of the last observable which emitted.
```

[expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYJ9G.jpg)

I can't find the operator to use for this. One solution could be to subscribe to all observable, and then make lastValue a Subject and update its value with next, but I would like to avoid subscribing to all the observable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `merge` to merge the two observables into one and the values are returned in the order they're emitted.. so when subscribing you'll always receive the latest value..

```js
merge(obs1, obs2).subscribe(result => {console.log(result)})
```

if the observables complete you can combine the above with `takeLast` to get the last x values emitted.

You can also wrap the implementation and make your own `BehaviourSubject`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was searching for, tried mergeAll but didn't work with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need `combineLatest`:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs'; 

combineLatest(obs1, obs2)
    .subscribe(([valueOfObs1, valueOfObs2]) => //...
```

Comment: it's returning me an array with the values of each observable, I just want the value of the last which emitted.